# script for multiplying radio button value and a fixed value

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, acrobat

I am creating a form in adobe acrobat XI pro.  I have a field that needs to be the PRODUCT of a radio button selection (values are 0 - 5) and a fixed number (i.e. 4).  I am stumped on getting the correct script.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The simiplest way would be adding the following to the Calculation event of the field where the result should appear:

```
if (this.getField("theRadioButton").value != "Off") {
event.value = this.getField("theRadioButton").value * 4
}
```

And that should do it.